# event delegation not working for checkbox and li

Tags: jquery

I have checkboxs within my li, I use `$(document).on('mouseenter','ul li', function)` to try to delegate but it doesn't seem work. I moved my mouse over even to the checkbox, the function did not stop from executed..

I can't select li, I have to do it with $(document), because my li will be dynamic..

Comment: What's not working? Can you post the whole javascript code?

Comment: There will be only `li` elements dynamic or also `ul` element. If `ul` wont be dynamic, then you can use `$('ul').on('mouseenter', 'li', function)`

Comment: `mouseenter` events cannot be delegated (they only trigger the handler if the pointer enters the bound element, not any of its descendants). Use `mouseover` instead.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I tried mouseover, still not solve the problem

Comment: @Emanuele, can you reproduce the problem in a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: ops, my bad, it's not checkbox, it's the label for it, no wonder..

Answer (score 0):

Better use **`.change()`** event handler instead of `mouseenter`

```
$('ul').on('change','li input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  //Your code
 });
```

**Updates:**
Based on your comments, try to use **`.hover`** event

```
$(document).on('hover','ul li', function() {
  //Your code
 });
```

Comment: I want to use mouseenter for the li to do something

Comment: @zzlalani Thanks for letting me to know the mistake

Answer (score 0):

rather of `document` use your `ul li` here

```
$('ul li').on('mouseenter', function() {

});
```

Also check How I'm using the last parameter `function`

**EDIT:**

PS: Although you're using the `on` function for the event it is good practice to have your jquery code within `$(document).ready(function () {});`

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/LQw5K/